# Powershell - How to programatically move and resize Citrix windows

Tags: powershell, citrix

I've searched through the entire internet twice ;) but still haven't found a solution to my issue.

I have created a powershell script to place open windows where I want them to be on the desktop, it works fine for the local applications like Messenger on Outlook. But moving a Citrix window is not that straightforward.

I can get the Id, name and mainWindowTitle for it, but Get-Process just returns an object of type system.diagnostics.process. (wfica32)

The error thrown from this is:

> Cannot convert argument "hWnd", with value: "System.Object[]", for
> "GetWindowRect" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot convert the
> "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Ob ject[]" to type
> "System.IntPtr"." At C:\temp\PlaceMyWindows.ps1:77 char:9 $Return =
> [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle) CategoryInfo :
> NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Any ideas on how to move these wfica32 citrix windows using powershell? Or CSharp for that matter?

```
    Function Set-Window {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.
        .DESCRIPTION
            Sets the window size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) of
            a process window.
        .PARAMETER ProcessName
            Name of the process to determine the window characteristics
        .PARAMETER X
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.
        .PARAMETER Y
            Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.
        .PARAMETER Width
            Set the width of the window.
        .PARAMETER Height
            Set the height of the window.
        .PARAMETER Passthru
            Display the output object of the window.
        .NOTES                         
            Name: Set-Window
            Author: Boe Prox
            Version History
                1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015
                    - Initial build
        .OUTPUT
            System.Automation.WindowInfo
        .EXAMPLE
            Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 2040 -Y 142 -Passthru
            ProcessName Size     TopLeft  BottomRight
            ----------- ----     -------  -----------
            powershell  1262,642 2040,142 3302,784   
            Description
            -----------
            Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe
        
    #>
    [OutputType('System.Automation.WindowInfo')]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ProcessName,
        [int]$X,
        [int]$Y,
        [int]$Width,
        [int]$Height,
        [switch]$Passthru
    )
    Begin {
        Try{
            [void][Window]
        } Catch {
        Add-Type @"
              using System;
              using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
              public class Window {
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
                [DllImport("User32.dll")]
                public extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
              }
              public struct RECT
              {
                public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
                public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
                public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
                public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
              }
"@
        }
    }
    Process {
        $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
        $Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {            
            $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left            
        }
        If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
            $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
        }
        If ($Return) {
            $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Passthru')) {
            $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If ($Return) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
                $Size = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                $TopLeft = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left, $Rectangle.Top
                $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                If ($Rectangle.Top -lt 0 -AND $Rectangle.LEft -lt 0) {
                    Write-Warning "Window is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                }
                $Object = [pscustomobject]@{
                    ProcessName = $ProcessName
                    Size = $Size
                    TopLeft = $TopLeft
                    BottomRight = $BottomRight
                }
                $Object.PSTypeNames.insert(0,'System.Automation.WindowInfo')
                $Object            
            }
        }
    }
}



Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize

Get-Process Messenger | Set-Window -X 2500 -Y 600 -Width 947 -Height 807 -Passthru
Get-Process OUTLOOK | Set-Window -X 1720 -Y 0 -Width 1720 -Height 1400 -Passthru

Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle -like '*Oracle*'}  | Set-Window -X 0 -Y 0 -Width 1720 -Height 1400 -Passthru

pause
```

Actually edited it today, and it runs without errors, but still does not move any Citrix windows (wfica32.exe)`

```
Clear

Function Set-Window {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Retrieve/Set the window size and coordinates of a process window.

.DESCRIPTION
Retrieve/Set the size (height,width) and coordinates (x,y) 
of a process window.

.PARAMETER ProcessName
Name of the process to determine the window characteristics. 
(All processes if omitted).

.PARAMETER Id
Id of the process to determine the window characteristics. 

.PARAMETER X
Set the position of the window in pixels from the left.

.PARAMETER Y
Set the position of the window in pixels from the top.

.PARAMETER Width
Set the width of the window.

.PARAMETER Height
Set the height of the window.

.PARAMETER Passthru
Returns the output object of the window.

.NOTES
Name:   Set-Window
Author: Boe Prox
Version History:
    1.0//Boe Prox - 11/24/2015 - Initial build
    1.1//JosefZ   - 19.05.2018 - Treats more process instances 
                                 of supplied process name properly
    1.2//JosefZ   - 21.02.2019 - Parameter Id

.OUTPUTS
None
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object

.EXAMPLE
Get-Process powershell | Set-Window -X 20 -Y 40 -Passthru -Verbose
VERBOSE: powershell (Id=11140, Handle=132410)

Id          : 11140
ProcessName : powershell
Size        : 1134,781
TopLeft     : 20,40
BottomRight : 1154,821

Description: Set the coordinates on the window for the process PowerShell.exe

.EXAMPLE
$windowArray = Set-Window -Passthru
WARNING: cmd (1096) is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate.

    PS C:\>$windowArray | Format-Table -AutoSize

  Id ProcessName    Size     TopLeft       BottomRight  
  -- -----------    ----     -------       -----------  
1096 cmd            199,34   -32000,-32000 -31801,-31966
4088 explorer       1280,50  0,974         1280,1024    
6880 powershell     1280,974 0,0           1280,974     

Description: Get the coordinates of all visible windows and save them into the
             $windowArray variable. Then, display them in a table view.

.EXAMPLE
Set-Window -Id $PID -Passthru | Format-Table
​‌‍
  Id ProcessName Size     TopLeft BottomRight
  -- ----------- ----     ------- -----------
7840 pwsh        1024,638 0,0     1024,638

Description: Display the coordinates of the window for the current 
             PowerShell session in a table view.



#>
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Name')]
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$False,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True, ParameterSetName='Name')]
    [string]$ProcessName='*',
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,
        ValueFromPipeline=$False,              ParameterSetName='Id')]
    [int]$Id,
    [int]$X,
    [int]$Y,
    [int]$Width,
    [int]$Height,
    [switch]$Passthru
)
Begin {
    Try { 
        [void][Window]
    } Catch {
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public class Window {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(
            IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public extern static bool MoveWindow( 
            IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(
            IntPtr handle, int state);
        }
        public struct RECT
        {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }
"@
    }
}
Process {
    $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
    If ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Id') ) {
        $Processes = Get-Process -Id $Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } else {
        $Processes = Get-Process -Name "$ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    if ( $null -eq $Processes ) {
        If ( $PSBoundParameters['Passthru'] ) {
            Write-Warning 'No process match criteria specified'
        }
    } else {
        $Processes | ForEach-Object {
            $Handle = $_.MainWindowHandle
            Write-Verbose "$($_.ProcessName) `(Id=$($_.Id), Handle=$Handle`)"
            if ( $Handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero ) { return }
            $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('X')) {
                $X = $Rectangle.Left            
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Y')) {
                $Y = $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Width')) {
                $Width = $Rectangle.Right - $Rectangle.Left
            }
            If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Height')) {
                $Height = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
            }
            If ( $Return ) {
                $Return = [Window]::MoveWindow($Handle, $x, $y, $Width, $Height,$True)
            }
            If ( $PSBoundParameters['Passthru'] ) {
                $Rectangle = New-Object RECT
                $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
                If ( $Return ) {
                    $Height      = $Rectangle.Bottom - $Rectangle.Top
                    $Width       = $Rectangle.Right  - $Rectangle.Left
                    $Size        = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size        -ArgumentList $Width, $Height
                    $TopLeft     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Left , $Rectangle.Top
                    $BottomRight = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates -ArgumentList $Rectangle.Right, $Rectangle.Bottom
                    If ($Rectangle.Top    -lt 0 -AND 
                        $Rectangle.Bottom -lt 0 -AND
                        $Rectangle.Left   -lt 0 -AND
                        $Rectangle.Right  -lt 0) {
                        Write-Warning "$($_.ProcessName) `($($_.Id)`) is minimized! Coordinates will not be accurate."
                    }
                    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Id          = $_.Id
                        ProcessName = $_.ProcessName
                        Size        = $Size
                        TopLeft     = $TopLeft
                        BottomRight = $BottomRight
                    }
                    $Object
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}


Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle -like '*Oracle*'} | Set-Window -X 20 -Y 40 -Width 100 -Height 100 -Passthru -Verbose
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle -like '*Messenger*'} | Set-Window -X 20 -Y 40 -Width 600 -Height 600 -Passthru -Verbose
```

Returns the following:

```
   Id Name                 MainWindowTitle                                                                                    
   -- ----                 ---------------                                                                                    
 6432 ApplicationFrameHost Kalkulator                                                                                         
 9060 Calculator           Kalkulator                                                                                         
11860 chrome               Powershell - How to programatically move and resize Citrix windows - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
 8616 Messenger            Messenger                                                                                                                                                  
16692 powershell           Administrator: Windows PowerShell                                                                  
 4188 powershell_ise       Windows PowerShell ISE                                                                             
11272 SystemSettings       Innstillinger                                                                                      
13824 Teams                Regnskap (4819) | Microsoft Teams                                                                  
10804 TextInputHost        Microsoft Text Input Application                                                                   
16036 wfica32              Oracle SQL Developer : Welcome Page - \\Remote                                                     
10320 WWAHost              Netflix                                                                                            


VERBOSE: wfica32 (Id=2340, Handle=0)
VERBOSE: wfica32 (Id=16036, Handle=723242)

VERBOSE: Messenger (Id=8616, Handle=132416)

Id          : 16036
ProcessName : wfica32
Size        : 2161,1400
TopLeft     : 3138,90
BottomRight : 5299,1490

Id          : 8616
ProcessName : Messenger
Size        : 600,600
TopLeft     : 20,40
BottomRight : 620,640
```

Comment: The Set-Window function isn't something I've made myself, found it while searching the vast internets for how to move applications around..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when using the script from https://github.com/proxb/PowerShell_Scripts/blob/master/Set-Window.ps1.
Apparently there is a newer version 1.2 available at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SciProfile/0.3.0/Content/PSModuleUtils%5CFunctions%5CSet-Window.ps1 that claims to handle multiple processes better. I don't know, because I didn't try it.

The problem is that on the line 78:

```
    $Handle = (Get-Process -Name $ProcessName).MainWindowHandle
```

Get-Process may return multiple window handles. When the line 89:

```
        $Return = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle,[ref]$Rectangle)
```

tries to use a single handle, it gets multiple. I opened an powershell window and looked at the output of Get-process:

```
>> Get-Process -Name "cmd" | Format-Table MainWindowHandle, StartTime, Id -AutoSize
MainWindowHandle StartTime              Id
---------------- ---------              --
          855904 20.10.2022 10.34.39  4324
               0 13.10.2022 14.16.05  5028
        13240562 20.10.2022 10.39.39  7708
          987022 20.10.2022 10.37.39 15508
```

It seems that Id 5028 is definitely not suitable, because it's handle is 0. I know that I just spawned a new "cmd.exe" window and that's what I want to use. The latest of these processes is 7708, so I need a system to select that one automatically. This was accomplished by changing line 78 to:

```
    $HandleArray = Get-Process -Name $ProcessName | Sort-Object -Property StartTime -Descending
    if ($HandleArray.Length -Gt 1) {
        $Handle = $HandleArray[0].MainWindowHandle
    } else {
        $Handle = $HandleArray.MainWindowHandle
    }
```

Big thanks to Dan at https://blog.osull.com/2019/07/18/resize-browser-window-with-powershell/ who wrote about this specific problem and helped me to find a solution.